# Rare bug with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I were using variadic templates in a program and it's come up an unexpected error. I isolated the error and I has shocked it:

```
#include<cctype> 
#include<iostream> // try to delete this line

class A 
{ 
    public: 
        void constructor() 
        {   } 

        template<typename... Args> 
        void constructor( int (*f)(int), Args... args ) 
        { 
            // process( f ) 
            constructor( args... ); 
        } 

        template<typename... Args> 
        A( Args... args ) 
        { 
            constructor( args... ); 
        } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    A a; 
    a.constructor( std::isspace ); // ok

    A b( std::isspace ); // error

    return 0; 
}
```

If you delete the line "#include iostream", the source is compiled alright. However, if you put this line, the compiler throw an error:

```
prov.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prov.cpp:32:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
prov.cpp:32:22: note: candidates are:
prov.cpp:18:7: note: A::A(Args ...) [with Args = {}]
prov.cpp:18:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prov.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr A::A(const A&)
prov.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const A&’
prov.cpp:4:7: note: constexpr A::A(A&&)
prov.cpp:4:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘A&&’
```

I'm using this g++ version: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11precise2) 4.7.2
and I'm compiling with this flags: `g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 prov.cpp -o prov`

I don't understand why compiler throws this error. Is it a possible bug?

Comment: You give it a function that is overloaded, how should the compiler chose between overloads on which of the std::isspace you wanted?

Comment: Why are you immediately assuming it's a compiler bug? That's awfully confident...

Comment: I'm not assuming it's a compiler bug. In the title I've used interrogative sentence and in the post i I wonder if it's a possible bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `<cctype>` defines a single function [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), but adding `<iostream>` adds another overload for [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace) that is pulled in from `<locale>`. The one from `<cctype>` is

```
int isspace( int ch );
```

The one from `<locale>` is

```
template< class charT >
bool isspace( charT ch, const locale& loc );
```

With both included, the `std::isspace` becomes ambiguous and hence your code fails. This becomes visible only when you route it through your real ctor (instead of `constructor`) because then the compiler can't decide what to forward. OTOH, the method `constructor` takes a parameter which already tells the compiler how to choose from both overloads.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I've undertund the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a compiler bug or even a problem with variadic templates, `std::isspace` is simply overloaded. When calling `.constructor` directly, the first argument `int (*f)(int)` gives the compiler enough information to select the correct overload, while a generic argument does not. This is easily demonstrated with an example:

```
// our std::isspace
void foo(int){}
void foo(double){}

void test1(void (*f)(int)){}

template<class T>
void test2(T v){}

int main(){
  test1(foo); // compiles, compiler sees you want the 'int' overload
  test2(foo); // error, compiler has no clue which overload you want
              // and which type to deduce 'T' as
}
```

You can fix this in two ways:

```
int (*f)(int) = std::isspace; // assign to variable, giving the compiler the information
A b(f); // already has concrete type here

// or
A b(static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace)); // basically the same as above, in one step
```