# Build cython error

Tags: c++, macos, cython

I am using the cython code from here:

https://github.com/amueller/slic-python

It works for me previously on MacOS Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to recompile this on MacOS Maverick (with latest cython and numpy), I got the following error when compiling .cpp file generated by cython:

```
_slic.cpp:5277:13: error: call to 'isspace' is ambiguous
        if (isspace(*ts))
            ^~~~~~~
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Usually the compiler provides the different possibilities for calling `isspace` from. Could you provide more complete error log, or is that all you have? - it sounds like includes "collision": you may have a look at this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15434417/1715716).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Cython trying to find the implementation of `isspace` and finding two seperate implementations: `libstdc++` (the GCC library) and `libc++` (the clang C++ standard library that is the default in 10.9).

We've raised this issue with the Cython devs, but currently no official fix exists. However, the solution is actually quite easy! Once the `_slic.cpp` file has been created by Cython, you can make it compile by changing all instances of `isspace` to `std::isspace`.